# Does Windows have a longer shutdown time than Unix-like operating systems, and why?

Tags: linux, windows, mac, android-x86

I've tested many different operating systems on the same machine. Windows 7, 8, 8.1, OS X, Ubuntu, Linux Mint,  Android x86, and Remix OS.

All the Unix-like/based operating systems had in common a near zero shutdown time,  maybe like 3 seconds.

All the Windows versions took considerably longer to shut down,  I am talking about 30 seconds to one minute.

Is there a general reason for this?

Comment: MS-DOS shutdown was instantaneous: switch off the power and that was it.

Comment: my win10 machines shuts down in 1 second

Comment: @Keltari I haven't tried 10 yet but I suppose it would be interesting to see if there's any difference.